# How can I change a UdpClient port after I established it a first time (Only one usage of each socket address is normally permitted)

Tags: c#, udp, udpclient

So i'm trying to make something that allows the user to change connections..(disregarded the IP code because that part isn't erroring.. just the port)

```
    private readonly UdpClient _udpListener;
    private IPEndPoint _listeningEndPoint;

    public FeedbackListener( int feedbackPort )
    {
        _listeningEndPoint = new IPEndPoint( IPAddress.Any, _feedbackPort );            
        _udpListener = new UdpClient( _listeningEndPoint );
    }
```

so say the user connects once:

```
public FeedbackListener _feedback;

_feedback = new FeedbackListener(Convert.ToInt32(port));
```

and they try to disconnect and reconnect with a DIFFERENT port:

```
//_udpListener.Close();  tried this, just turns into another about accessing a disposed object
_feedback = new FeedbackListener(Convert.ToInt32(port));
```

i get this error: Only one usage of each socket address is normally permitted... so is there any way i can successfully change the port without getting this error?

Comment: If I don't new an IPEndPoint if it already exist but only change the `Port` property ( `_listeningEndPoint.Port = feedbackport`) it doesn't throw an error for me. Can you try if that works in your full-blown scenario?

Comment: hey rene.  just got back from lunch, will try this out in a few minutes and get back to you, thanks for responding

Comment: it worked!  thank you so much.  you can post what you said as an answer to this question so i can give you points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep only one instance of `IPEndPoint` and only update the  `Port` when you want to instantiate a new `UdpClient`

Something like:

```
private static IPEndPoint _listeningEndPoint = null;

public FeedbackListener( int feedbackPort )
{
    if ( _listeningEndPoint == null)
    {
       _listeningEndPoint =  new IPEndPoint( IPAddress.Any, feedbackport);
    }
    else
    {
        _listeningEndPoint.Port = feedbackport;
    } 
}
```